# VueJs + ASP.Net Core Web API Make a post request

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, vuejs3

I have a VueJs Frontend where I want to make a post request to my ASP.NET Core Web API. This is what the code in the VueJs app looks like:

```
methods: {
    async addProject(project){

        const res = await fetch('https://localhost:44357/test/data/CreateProject', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            //mode: 'no-cors',
            body: JSON.stringify(project)
        })

        const data = await res.json()

        this.projects = [...this.projects, data]
    },
},
```

The url could be missleading so I want to clarify that this url is mapped inside the Web API to a method inside the controller which should get a project object which has only a name attribute in it.

Now for the ASP.NET Core Web API I have set up cors so that I can make calls to it:

```
services.AddCors();
...
app.UseCors(
    options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080").AllowAnyMethod()
);
```

Now for the route mapping I did it like this:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "test",
    pattern: "test/data/CreateProject",
    defaults: new { controller = "Models", action = "createproject" }
);

//the function:
[HttpPost]
public string CreateProject([FromBody] Project data)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(data.Name);
    return "Ok";
}
```

Now the error that I get is that I cannot make a call because of cors policy which is weird for me. I thought I allowed the vuejs app to make calls. I then installed the chrome plugin CORS unblock which didnt solve this basically but in the network tab inside the website inspector I can see that there is a Post Request with status code 204. I just want to confirm that the data arrives in my Web Api. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to change in order to make this happen?

Comment: Is there any authentication in the API ?

Comment: `app.UseAuthorization();` is in it. Would that be a problem though? "AllowedHosts" : "*" is inside the appsettings.json

Comment: [Requests with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#requests_with_credentials)

Comment: Please share the detailed CORS error message without using that chrome plugin. And you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to check if you enable CORS correctly. Besides, please check if you call `UseCors` after `UseRouting` but before `UseAuthorization`.

Comment: @FeiHan When I do the request this message appears: `Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44357/test/data/CreateProject' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I also changed the position of the `UseCors` call but didnt change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.UseCors(
    options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
);
```

Using AllowAnyHeader function fixed it